# Shell script outputting nothing into file

Tags: shell-script, files

I am trying to make a small program that uses Google Translate to mix up sentences/files. Its output file is only three bytes and appears to have nothing in it.

I am using the `trans` command to translate.

first part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG="en"
CONTINUE=2
cd /root && CONTINUE=1
#Language Randomizer
function rl(){
    LANGNUM=$(shuf -i 1-81 -n1)
    
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 1 ]]
    then
        LANG="af"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 2 ]]
    then
            LANG="am"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 3 ]]
    then
            LANG="ar"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 4 ]]
    then
            LANG="az"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 5 ]]
    then
            LANG="ba"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 6 ]]
    then
            LANG="be"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 7 ]]
    then
            LANG="bg"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 8 ]]
    then    
            LANG="bn"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 9 ]]
    then
            LANG="bs"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 10 ]]
    then
            LANG="ca"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 11 ]]
    then
        LANG="ceb"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 12 ]]
    then
            LANG="co"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 13 ]]
    then
            LANG="cs"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 14 ]]
    then
            LANG="cy"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 15 ]]
    then
            LANG="da"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 16 ]]
    then
            LANG="de"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 17 ]]
    then
            LANG="el"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 18 ]]
    then    
            LANG="emj"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 19 ]]
    then
            LANG="eo"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 20 ]]
    then
            LANG="es"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 21 ]]
    then
        LANG="et"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 22 ]]
    then
            LANG="eu"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 23 ]]
    then
            LANG="fa"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 24 ]]
    then
            LANG="fi"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 25 ]]
    then
            LANG="fj"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 26 ]]
    then
            LANG="fr"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 27 ]]
    then
            LANG="fy"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 28 ]]
    then    
            LANG="ga"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 29 ]]
    then
            LANG="gd"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 30 ]]
    then
            LANG="gl"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 31 ]]
    then
        LANG="gu"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 32 ]]
    then
            LANG="ha"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 33 ]]
    then
            LANG="haw"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 34 ]]
    then
            LANG="he"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 35 ]]
    then
            LANG="hi"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 36 ]]
    then
            LANG="hmn"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 37 ]]
    then
            LANG="hr"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 38 ]]
    then    
            LANG="ht"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 39 ]]
    then
            LANG="hu"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 40 ]]
    then
            LANG="hy"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 41 ]]
    then
        LANG="id"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 42 ]]
    then
            LANG="ig"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 43 ]]
    then
            LANG="is"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 44 ]]
    then
            LANG="it"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 45 ]]
    then
            LANG="ja"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 46 ]]
    then
            LANG="jv"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 47 ]]
    then
            LANG="ka"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 48 ]]
    then    
            LANG="kk"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 49 ]]
    then
            LANG="km"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 50 ]]
    then
            LANG="kn"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 51 ]]
    then
        LANG="ko"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 52 ]]
    then
            LANG="ku"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 53 ]]
    then
            LANG="ku"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 54 ]]
    then
            LANG="la"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 55 ]]
    then
            LANG="lb"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 56 ]]
    then
            LANG="lo"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 57 ]]
    then
            LANG="lt"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 58 ]]
    then    
            LANG="lv"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 59 ]]
    then
            LANG="mg"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 60 ]]
    then
            LANG="mhr"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 61 ]]
    then
        LANG="mi"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 62 ]]
    then
            LANG="mk"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 63 ]]
    then
            LANG="ml"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 64 ]]
    then
            LANG="mn"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 65 ]]
    then
            LANG="mr"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 66 ]]
    then
            LANG="mrj"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 67 ]]
    then
            LANG="ms"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 68 ]]
    then    
            LANG="mt"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 69 ]]
    then
            LANG="mww"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 70 ]]
    then
            LANG="my"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 71 ]]
    then
        LANG="ne"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 72 ]]
    then
            LANG="nl"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 73 ]]
    then
            LANG="no"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 74 ]]
    then
            LANG="ny"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 75 ]]
    then
            LANG="otq"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 76 ]]
    then
            LANG="pa"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 77 ]]
    then
            LANG="pap"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 78 ]]
    then    
            LANG="pl"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 79 ]]
    then
            LANG="ps"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 80 ]]
    then
            LANG="pt"
    fi
    if [[ $LANGNUM -eq 81 ]]
    then
            LANG="ro"
    fi
}
```

Second part:

```
if [[ $CONTINUE -eq 2 ]]
then
    exit
fi
cd ~/
echo "Please Enter Path To The File To Be Translated"
read IFILE
echo "Please Enter Name For Output"
read OFILE
rl
sudo trans :$LANG file://$IFILE > /root/TransHistory142.txt
while  [[ $X -le 10 ]]
do
    rl
    sudo trans :$LANG file:///root/TransHistory142.txt > /root/TransHistory141.txt
    rl
    sudo trans :$LANG file:///root/TransHistory141.txt > /root/TransHistory142.txt
    ((X++))
done


sudo trans :en file:///root/TransHistory142.txt > /home/$OFILE
echo "Saved To /home/$OFILE "
```

Comment: You should convert all those if statements into a case.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to execute the `trans` command? note that the redirections to files in `/root` will still be executed by the unprivileged shell

Comment: Welcome, could you explain the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: @jesse_b I think better would be just list the langs in a file and then just `cat file | shuf | tail -1`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which output file are you talking about? I see at least three output files: `/root/TransHistory141.txt`, `/root/TransHistory142.txt` and `/home/$OFILE`. Also, if this script is executed by a non-root user, the redirections to `/root` are unlikely to work, because the user has no right to write to `/root` (except if you changed `/root` permissions).

Comment: @berndbausch /home/$OFILE. i used two files (transhistory142 and 141) to store the information for the next translate, and the cd /root is to make it so if it doesnt complete the cd /root, it knows you did not execute it in sudo, and exits the script. looking in transhistory142 + 141, they also have nothing....

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity the while loop is to loop it ten times

Comment: @CheeseCatChuck Ok, but I would like to understand what is it for. To add more randomness?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity exactly. putting one thing through gt and then back won't mess it up, do it 20 times!

Answer (score 1):

The only relevant line in the question is `sudo trans :en file:///root/TransHistory142.txt > /home/$OFILE`. If the execution of the script ever reaches that line the file *will* be created and its contents *will* be replaced with the standard output of the command. This is irrespective of whether `sudo` exists, whether `trans` is a valid command, whether `file:///root/TransHistory142.txt` exists, or whether the command succeeds, because Bash is creating/emptying the file before the command even runs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `>` operator to write to the text files. This will overwrite existing data in the file. You may want to try using `>>` to append data to the file.

Comment: I was using > instead of >> so i could overwrite the previous file and not have to have 20 files. but i will try that anyway, as i do not know that much about some linux commands

Comment: Hmm.. after looking some more at the Files TransHistory142 And 141, I Noticed That They Just Have 3  "Enter"'s In Them. There Was Three Lines In My Test Document, So I Think It Might Be Outputting Everything BUT The Words? IDK, i just thought that that could be a possiblity.

Comment: Instead of using the ```>``` or ```>>``` operators, you can try using the ```tee``` command. Pass your program output to ```tee``` and it will output the contents to both a file and stdout (your terminal likely). More info [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)

Comment: yeah, using tee helped a bit, but now like 50% of the time its just exiting with nothing.

Comment: i also changed it to sleep 0.5 seconds inbewteen each translation, which helped alot