# Randomizer script failing to randomize

Tags: bash, sort, zenity

I am having a problem where [this project](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632318/shell-script-outputting-nothing-into-file) is not randomizing anything.

My new code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function ReRoll(){
    sort -R languagecodes.txt > /dev/null
    sleep 0.5
    LANG=$(head -n 1 /home/pi/GT-bash-client/languagecodes.txt)
    sleep 0.1
}
INPUT=$(zenity --entry --title="Input" --text="Please enter string to be translated.")
while [[ $X -le 10 ]]
do
    ((X++))
    ReRoll
    PTRAN=$(./translate.sh auto $LANG $INPUT)
    sleep 0.1
    echo $X
    echo $PTRAN
    INPUT=$PTRAN
    
done
DONE=$(./translate.sh auto en $INPUT) 
echo $DONE
```

languagecodes.txt:

```
af
sq
am
ar
hy
az
eu
be
bn
bs
bg
ca
ceb
zh-CN
zh-TW
co
hr
cs
da
nl
en
eo
et
fi
fr
fy
gl
ka
de
el
gu
ht
ha
haw
he
hi
hmn
hu
is
ig
id
ga
it
ja
jv
kn
kk
km
rw
ko
ku
ky
lo
la
lv
lt
lb
mk
mg
ms
ml
mt
mi
mr
mn
my
ne
no
ny
or
ps
fa
pl
pt
pa
ro
ru
sm
gd
sr
st
sn
sd
si
sk
sl
so
es
su
sw
sv
tl
tg
ta
tt
te
th
tr
tk
uk
ur
ug
uz
vi
cy
xh
yi
yo
zu
```

The translating script is [here.](https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/GT-bash-client)

anyway, the output when i enter "Hello There, My Friend" is always:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/GT-bash-client $ sudo bash TransScrambler.sh
1
Hallo daar, my vriend!
2
Hallo daar, my vriend!
3
Hallo daar, my vriend!
4
Hallo daar, my vriend!
5
Hallo daar, my vriend!
6
Hallo daar, my vriend!
7
Hallo daar, my vriend!
8
Hallo daar, my vriend!
9
Hallo daar, my vriend!
10
Hallo daar, my vriend!
11
Hallo daar, my vriend!
Hello there, my friend!
pi@raspberrypi:~/GT-bash-client $
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not storing the shuffled output from `languagecodes.txt` anywhere. You're sending the output of the shuffling into `/dev/null`, where it is gone forever. When you later store the head of your file into the LANG variable, you're just using the original unshuffled file.

Change your ReRoll function to this:

```
LANG=$(sort -R /home/pi/GT-bash-client/languagecodes.txt | head -1)
```

(No need for all the calls to `sleep` either.)

Comment: AH! I Thought `roll -R` would shuffle the actual file, not ouput it! that makes more sense now.

Comment: Glad this helps, thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: also i used the `sleep`s cuz it heped in the previous version of this, but it works fine without it

Answer (score 0):

Your sort call is the problem. Default output for sort command is to stdout. You call this function with >/dev/null specification. This means that your script doesn't print anything and rather than this, it will not rewrite your languagecodes text file. If you want to rewrite languagecodes.txt file with some random sort you have to tell sort command "-o parameter".

So you can rewrite your function like this:

```
function ReRoll(){
    sort -R languagecodes.txt -o "./languagecodes.txt" > /dev/null
    sleep 0.5
    LANG=$(head -n 1 /home/pi/GT-bash-client/languagecodes.txt)
    sleep 0.1
}
```